# Install PhoneGap 3.3 on Windows for Android (Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I've installed PhoneGap 2.9.1 on Windows and followed this tutorial for Eclipse:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html

Now I want to update PhoneGap and my project to PhoneGap 3.3, but I don't know, how to do that.

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install Nodejs, then install cordova using nodejs. 
Then you need to create Phonegap project, add required plugins to the project. These steps are described in the below link.

http://codingsquare.blogspot.in/2013/08/creating-cordova-3-android-project.html

Then you need to copy the app from www folder of your PhoneGap 2.9.1 app into the www folder in the root of the latest cordova project.

Then add the platform and you can import the project into eclipse.

Comment: Thanks, I will test it tomorrow and give you some feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

Also like this [tutorial](http://www.pycode.com/android/creating-a-phonegap-cordova-3.0-app-in-eclipse.html), was working fine for me.

- install NodeJS
- install Cordova
- create Project
- import the Project into Eclipse

best

M